# Regex lookahead complex pattern

Tags: php, regex

This code is replacing too many single pipes with double pipes.  To keep the change small, I'd prefer to simply correct the second regex so that it allows for spaces between the "|" and the ",".

So, the question is how to modify the second regex to *not* match `\|[[:blank:]]*[^,\r\n]`.

**Code:**

```
$patterns = array (
  '/\\\\\|,/', 
  "/(?<=[^,])\|(?=[^,\n\r])/"
);
$replacements = array (
  '|,', 
  '||'
);
$line = preg_replace ($patterns, $replacements, $line);
```

**Example:**

For the string: `"|DI|,|15| ,|C00413914|,||         ,|F|"`

Expected / desired result:

`"|DI|,|15| ,|C00413914|,||         ,|F|"`

Actual result:

`"|DI|,|15|| ,|C00413914|,|||         ,|F|"`

I've tried this, which didn't work:

- `"/(?<=[^,])\|(?=[[:blank:]]*[^,\n\r])/"`

**Please note:**

This question is for fixing a bug with the smallest change possible.  The current regex may be suboptimal (like using negative character classes instead of negative lookaround), but my first priority is to minimize the changes and not optimize the regex.

**Update:**

In other words, based on my interpretation of the original regex, the revised should match any single `|` followed by zero or more spaces that's NOT at the beginning or end of the line, NOT preceded by a comma, and NOT followed by `,`, `\r`, or `\n`.

**More examples:**

1. `5|foo` should match
2. `5| foo` should match
3. `5|,` should not match
4. `5| ,` should not match
5. `5|\r` should not match
6. `5| \r` should not match
7. `,||,` should not match
8. `,|| ,` should not match

*Discovered from applying the suggestions to real data.  The original regex appears to observe this behavior:*

9. `|foo|,` should not match. Pipe is first character on line.
10. `|foo| ,` should not match. Pipe is first character on line.
11. `,|foo|` should not match. Pipe is last character on line, newline may not exist (such as with EOF).
12. `,|foo|` should not match. Pipe + whitespace are last characters on line, newline may not exist (such as with EOF).

Comment: Try `"/(?<=[^,])\|(?=\|[[:blank:]]*[^,\r\n])/"`. If it does not work, please provide more sample input and expected output.

Comment: But which pipes you want to match? what is difference between these you want and dont't want to replace? Your example is not self-explanatory

Comment: @m.cekiera Please see the expected result. I don't want it to match any of the pipes in the sample input; none should be replaced by `||`.  I want the regex to work as-is, except not match those with space between the `|` and the `,`

Comment: @stribizhev I added more examples.  I believe yours doesn't match #1 & #2 (`5|foo` & `5| foo`), according to http://www.phpliveregex.com/

Comment: Please try with [`(?<!,)\|[[:blank:]]*+(?![,\n\r])`](https://regex101.com/r/xV5eD6/2), it will match the pipe and spaces after it if there are any. Or, if you only need to match the pipe, try using [`(?<!,)\|(?![[:blank:]]*[,\n\r])`](https://regex101.com/r/xV5eD6/3). Does either work as expected?

Comment: @stribizhev (edited) Those gave me most of what I needed.  I think the key was the `*+` (possessive).  The data yielded a couple of new cases I wasn't originally aware of: pipes at beginning / end of line (without newline characters), so I ended up with this [`(?<=[^,])(?<=.)\|(?=[[:blank:]]*+[^,\n\r])`](https://regex101.com/r/xV5eD6/4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regex you were looking for in the beginning can be written as

```
(?<!,)\|(?![[:blank:]]*[,\n\r])
```

It matches the pipe if there are no optional whitespaces followed by a comma or linebreaks, and that is not preceded by a comma.

Note in this regex example we do not need a possessive quantifier because inside a lookahead in PHP the possessive behavior is turned on by default due to internal optimizations..

Your final regex can also look like

```
(?<=[^\r\n,])\|(?=[[:blank:]]*+[^,\n\r])
```

It checks if a pipe is preceded by a character other than a comma or linebreaks, and is followed by 0 or more spaces not followed by a commq or linebreaks. Possessive behavior can be forced with `*+` if your PCRE library was compiled without optimizations.

Comment: Your second regex did the trick, and -- according to regex101.com -- is more efficient than my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
(?<=[^,])\|(?=[^,\n\r ])
```

if this in not what you mean, provide more input and desired output examples.